# what is the .net technology to replace Microsoft Transaction Server

Tags: .net, com+

MTS is a popular COM+ service to do distributed transation control. I am wondeirng what is the .Net replacement for it since Com+ will be phased out.

Comment: Didn't MTS (as a name) die with NT4? isn't it just COM+ services now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no replacement to MTS in .NET Framework, but it is very well integrated through `System.EnterpriseServices` namespace, specifically you could lookup `ServicedComponent` to get the transaction control feature you are looking for.
[Have a look at MSDN documentation of this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b84cbdx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

MSDTC still lives on, and is available in managed code via [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). So - use that. There are some COM+ things that *don't* really have direct counterparts; having a COM+ dll that runs in a different identity, or all the vastly over-complicated COM+ permissions/roles/groups/etc, but in truth you are usually better off writing a proper service (trivial in managed code) that accepts requests via any IPC method of your choosing.